# Why my miners are not using my stockpile?

Tags: banished

I decided to put a stockpile near my mine to minimize the resource move time, but instead they are just dropping the iron to the dirt, when there's a stockpile right in front of it. What I'm doing wrong?

Improving the question, is it true that miners only mine and do not drop the iron at the nearest stockpile?
[image: iron]

Well, it's getting real ironic how the guys at the quarry do their job but the miners don't:
[image: iron]

Comment: Actually, Stone-cutters deliver their stone under the long roofed area next to the Crane/Winch.  Laborers later move the stone to a stockpile.  If you don't have enough Laborers, the Stone-cutters will clean up the area when they run out in much the same way a Wood-cutter will clean out his yard when (s)he's created 5 stacks that haven't been picked up by laborers.  Question:  Is your Quarry closer to your population center than the mines in question?

Comment: My Mine and Quarry are at the same corner pictured above, but it wasn't shown due camera angle. That's why this is awkward. I have free laborers carrying the stone to it, but do not carry iron to the stockpile, even when they (mine and quary) are a one-square-road distance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Miners* **mine**. Nothing more.

*Laborers* **carry**.

Simply said they don't feel responsible to move their stuff. Others will do that.

> Laborer is a generic name in Banished for workers who do not have a set Profession. They carry out menial tasks such as clearing trees and carrying logs to storage as well as moving resources from one location to another.

On a wider note why the Laborers dont use that stockpile. Most likely they will fill them up in Build order or atleast try to fill the ones which are already in use.

[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Laborers)

Comment: Actually miners idle, eat and as I saw in other games of mine, throw iron at the nearest stockpile. It's funny because I've never seen a hunter leave his resources on the dirt, always in the closest barn. Actually all the guys working at gathering any resource drop them at their respective deposit. It's the first time I see they doing this

Comment: @GabrielRado Not entirely correct.  While most resource gatherers do generally clean up their work areas, I have frequently seen meat & leather left on the ground near a hunting cabin, and veggies in a field, etc.  This commonly happens when your gatherer discovers they are already too burdened, or when they decide to eat, warm up or idle after having produced the goods.  In any case, I've found that keeping at least 10% of my population as General Laborers is a Good Thing™.